# Understanding higher-kinded types - implementing trait functionality

Tags: scala

Trying to follow this example (taken from scala in action) for creating generic sum function for all collections

```
trait Summable[A] {
  def plus(a1: A, a2: A): A
  def init: A
}
object IntSummable extends Summable[Int] {
  def plus(a1: Int, a2: Int): Int = a1 + a2
  def init: Int = 0
}
trait Foldable[F[_]] {
  def foldLeft[A](xs: F[A], m: Summable[A]) : A
}
```

implementing foldLeft like this works fine :

```
  object ListFoldLeft extends Foldable[List] {
    def foldLeft[A](xs:List[A],m:Summable[A]) =
    xs.foldLeft(m.init)(m.plus)
  }
```

however, however, although the foldLeft function accepts two parameters (xs:List[A],m:Summable[A]), we send them  seperatly 
xs.foldLeft(m.init)(m.plus) and it works fine

but if I try to send them like this :

```
      object ListFoldLeft extends Foldable[List] {
        def foldLeft[A](xs:List[A],m:Summable[A]) =
            xs.foldLeft(m.init,m.plus)
       }
```

I get

```
<console>:18: error: too many arguments for method foldLeft: (z: B)(op: (B, A) => B)B
       xs.foldLeft(m.init,m.plus)
```

why ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like you try to call
`List . foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B` curried function with only one parameter list, and with invalid number of parameters in that defined parameter list.

List.foldLeft is a curried function

more about curried functions here:

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala

Comment: I think you are missing my point : why do I get too many arguments when trying to implement it like this :object ListFoldLeft extends Foldable[List] {
        def foldLeft[A](xs:List[A],m:Summable[A]) =
            xs.foldLeft(m.init,m.plus)
       }

Comment: xs is a List and you call foldLeft with one parameter list and in that parameterlist with invalid number of parameters.

Comment: @igx I believe you are invoking `List.foldLeft` instead of `ListFoldLeft.foldLeft` on `xs`

Comment: @Daenyth is right, you invoke foldLeft on a different type than you would like to

Comment: why this works fine: xs.foldLeft(m.init)(m.plus) and this xs.foldLeft(m.init,m.plus) fails due to too many arguments

Comment: because foldLeft is a curried function, foldLeft has two parameter lists with specified number of parameters and you try to use the first parameter list with invalid numebr of parameters. please check my original comment about curried functions